# Android Room Migration changing a columns data type without data loss

Tags: android, kotlin, database-migration, android-room

I have a table column named `tag` (TEXT) which will change to `tags` (TEXT)
the entity will change from `String` to List

I have written a converter for the column which converts the List with `Gson()`

how do I write migration for this query? 
I have tried to create a temp table and then inset values - but anable to convert tag to array.
Also, tag is nullable.

```
    private val migration_2_3: Migration = object : Migration(2, 3) {
        override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `TempEntity` (`id` TEXT NOT NULL, `tags` TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(`id`))")
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO `TempEntity` (`id`, `topicIds`,) SELECT `id`, arrayOf('\"[', topicId, ']\"') FROM Entity")
            database.execSQL("DROP TABLE Entity")
            database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE TempEntity RENAME TO Entity")
        }
    }
```